# Symfony2 Validator Component on Standalone (Conditional Validation)

Tags: php, symfony

I had an issue with the Symfony 2 Validator Component.

I want to use conditional validation groups without using annotation and object.

The goal is to have a legal number only whether the country is FR.

For instance: ( I removed all part which is not interesting ).

```
$data = array('country'=>'FR', 'legalNo'=>'');

$myCollection = new Assert\Collection(array(
    'country'=>array(
        'constraints'=>array(
            new Assert\NotBlank()
        )
    ),
    'legalNo'=>array(
        'groups'=>array('legal'),
        'constraints'=>array(
            new Assert\NotBlank(array('groups'=>'legal')),
            new Assert\Length(array('groups'=>'legal', 'min'=>14, 'max'=>14))
        )
    )
);
$validator = Validation::createValidator();
$violations = $validator->validateValue($data, $myCollection, array(Constraint::DEFAULT_GROUP/* Default */));
```

The `$violations` variable gives: "***Array[legalNo] : This value should not be blank***"

I don't understand why:

1 - The '*NotBlank*" legalNo constraint is used.

2 - Why "*Array*" was added as a prefix. It seems there is an error here :

( @see line 189 *Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator.php* : 
`$context->validateValue($value, $constraint, $groups);` 
The signature of the *ExecutionContext* `validateValue` function is:

```
public function validateValue($value, $constraints, $subPath = '', $groups = null)
```

So It seems the groups be used as the `subpath` variable .

**UPDATED:**

Ok, It seems there is a [WIP(working in process) pull request on this issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/4453).

So my question is:

- How can I do the conditional validation without this functionnality ? ( maybe by overriding the `Constraints\Collection` with a `addConstraint` function ? )